# Interest Question

Tags: finance

If somebody owes \$55k and pays it back in four years with 6.4% interest p.a, how much would it be if its compounded quarterly?

So I used $$A=P(1+i/4)^{4(4)}$$ and plugged it in as $$A=55000(1+.064/4)^{16}$$ but my answer was \$591,000? And I'm sure it's wrong so can someone please help explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math.SE! We don't like to do your homework for you :), so could you please update your question with your thoughts/attempts to do the problem and we will be happy to guide you further

Comment: Also, what is interest "p.a"?

Comment: Done, sorry about the error

Comment: "p.a." I'm assuming means per annum.

Comment: Are you sure you know how your calculator works, because https://www.google.com/search?q=(1%2B.064%2F4)^16

Comment: I got 70902.58 for the same calculation

Comment: you put in .64 instead of .064.  This returns the 591,000 that you got origonally.

Comment: Assuming you are making quarterly payments, you should use the present value of an annuity formula rather than the compound interest formula.  The compound interest formula would be right if there is just one lump sum payment at the end; but this is not how loans usually work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You have to calculate

$C_4=C_0\cdot \left(1+\frac{i}{m} \right)^{m\cdot n}= \$55,000\cdot \left(1+\frac{0.064}{4} \right)^{4\cdot 4}=\$70,902.58$

$\frac{0.064}{4}$ is the the quarterly interest rate. And n the amount of years. And m is the frequency of compounding (per year).

**Remark:**
As [Padding Ghost](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/178532/paddling-ghost) commented, you have inserted 0.64 instead of 0.064.

Answer (score 1):

As there is only 1 problem with your work, this answer will be short.  It seems you have mistakenly typed in $.64$ instead of $.064$.  This agrees with you're original value.  That is, $55000(1+.64/4)^{16} \approx 591,000$.  The correct value is obtained when you hit the right buttons and do the calculation $55000(1+.064/4)^{16} \approx 70900$.

Edit:  In the case that this is actually meant to be a loan repayment/annuity problem.  My answer will not give you the correct answer.  Please see the answer that paw88789 gives.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are making quarterly payments, rather than a single payment at the end,  you would use the present value of an annuity formula:

$ \$55000 = R\cdot\frac{1-1.016^{-16}}{.016}$

To find the quarterly payment size, $R$.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I understand it well now